# Jquery, Jcarousel smooth infinite scrolling

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am using jcarousel to auto scroll some images. I would like to know how to make them scroll in one fluid scroll with no pauses or stops.

Currently there is a pause and then it scrolls again. If I am not making myself clear then ask and I will try to explain a little better.

This is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 1,
        wrap: 'last',
        vertical: true,
        animation: 5000

    });
```

Comment: My jQuery plugin, simplyScroll should achieve what you want http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
auto: .01
```

you have it set to autoscroll every 1 second. I don't think a fluid scroll is possible, but this should look just about the same.

Comment: Thanks for that. Decide do it an easy way and use the jquery animate function.

Comment: This worked for me in addition to setting animation speed to a higher value (than the default). Like so:  `animation: 5000, auto: 0.01`

Answer (score 7):

This questions is as old as dirt, but I figured I give the updated solution.

```
$('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
    wrap: 'circular',
    animation: {
        duration: 3000,
        easing:   'linear',
    }
  });
  $('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll({
      interval: 0
  });
```

Comment: Best answer of them all.

Comment: Works for me too, but what if I want to directly jump to a picture without the transition? Your solution does actually "disable" the pagination's function...

Answer (score 2):

To me it scrolls "smoother" when used linear easing instead of swing.

```
auto:   .01,
easing: 'linear'
```

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 0.1,
        scroll: 10,
        wrap: 'circular',
        animation: 10000,
        easing: 'linear'
      });
  });` - easing made all the difference

Answer (score 0):

- Open jquery.jcarousel.min.js
- Beautify the script using http://jsbeautifier.org
- find and replace "this.options.auto * 1E3" with "0" (zero)

Something like:

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel){   
    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.

    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto:   1,
        animation:2000,
        easing: 'linear',
        wrap: 'circular',
        scroll:1,
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
});
```

thats all. :)